# Get component DOM property on React

Tags: reactjs, dom

> I am trying to understand how to develop with React with its own
>   reactive programming style. It is still hard for me think in this way.

I have two main components: `Header` and `Title`.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return <div className='header'>
            { this.tabs.map(t => <Title title={t.props.title}/>) }
        </div>;
    }
}

class Title extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <span className='title'>
            { this.props.title }
        </span>;
    }
}
```

I need to get data from `.header`, first and last `Title` DOM elements to do some calculation to **center `Title` on `Header` consideration an active `Title` concept**. I could do that easily with document.querySelector, but it doesn't seem the React-way to do it.

I guess I only could do what I want after all `Title` are rendered (or mounted, don't know).

I already tried to attach a `ref` attribute with an anonymous function on `Title`, but this function is called for every `Title`. Maybe this is the way but something is missing!

**Q:** Is there any sort of method that is called when all children are rendered/mount?
**Q:** Supposing there is a method, how can I get the DOM reference from `Title` that I need without sounding to much imperative?

Comment: u should import Title component with ur props or state so u can access it in ur header!  look on youtube there is an nice tutorial for ur problem. `export default class Menu extends React.Component {constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: 'title '

    }; }`

Comment: how can I find it there?

Comment: You must not working with DOM when using react. Use state or prop and react will handle the DOM for you.

Comment: @Petroff I need to calculate how to center a element using container width and `Title` width considering offsetWidth. Can I do that without using DOM?

Comment: @richard import mystyles from './my.scss'; import ur css or sass file and do it with css , ur components will be rendered by react. ur reference in the dom for title is title

Comment: You already got it, refs prop on child components suits your use case though it's not common. React encourages declarative rendering while you have to imperatively manipulate the DOM, this is what's refs used for.

Comment: @Xlee Is there any better approach?

Comment: @Richard Probably switch to jQuery, that's how we happily write imperative style code. Reacts declarative approach is way hipsters thing 

Comment: Btw, the refined official docs is always ur friend: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html, it's not that hatchy as it seems. IMO, declarative means both parent n children have no assumptions/knowledge about each other thus get decoupled while ur case isn't that;(

Comment: does it could mean that declarative approach may not be fit here!?